# IIS AppPool shutdown due to inactivity

Tags: iis, web-applications, windows

Using Windows 10 / IIS 10

I have a Web Application and have set the following:

- AppPool: Start Mode = AlwaysRunning
- Web Application: Enable Preload = true

But still, the web application gets shut down:

- A worker process with process id of 'nnnnn' serving application pool 'Ssss' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.

Okay, the solution is to set the AppPool's Idle-Timeout (minutes) to either be a large number or (I'm guessing zero to signify "don't").

However, my understanding was that "AlwaysRunning" overrode the Idle-Timeout - evidently not.

Can someone either explain or point me to something that explains the exactly what each setting does, and how they (don't?) relate to each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46742416/10519755/) you should set the Idle Timeout to 0, even though it may contradict Microsoft documentation.